# How to add Cloudwatch Insights visualization to dashboard

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I'm interested in using AWS Cloudwatch Insights to create a dashboard for my application. I have a lambda function that I have measured how many times it is invoked which I would like to graph and include on the dashboard. My data looks like this:

[image: d]

I've added the data above to my dashboard but I want the visualization graph to appear instead. I've googled, read aws docs, and attempted to recreate the data sets using dashboard metrics but I've been unable to make this work so far. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was changed and is possible now

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As of 2024 this is possible.

After speaking with an AWS Support rep, there is no way to do this currently.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/) it's possible to add CloudWatch insights to a dashboard. However, you can only visualize line, stacked area, pie, and bar charts.

[image: CloudWatch Insights Visualization Options]